# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes) MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

Пришлось поменять сервер - и тут возникла проблема с подключением к базе данных, а если быть точнее, то с подключением из `Laravel`.

На старом сервере была `MySQL 8.0`, тут же - `MariaDB 10.5.15`, вроде как, они работают на одном драйвере, но, может быть, ошибаюсь.

Команды в терминале выглядят вот так:

```
mysql -u root
use table;
select * from users;
```

Всё работает правильно, как и нужно.

`PhpMyAdmin` тоже работает правильно, а вот сайт:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = 123@gmail.com limit 1)
```

Получается как-то так, пробовал выдавать права (хотя не понимаю зачем, это же root), пробовал:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('root');
```

Никак не помогает, пробовал создавать новых пользователей - тоже не работает: как я понимаю, вся проблема именно в подключении из `Laravel`.

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Этот код `config/database.php` я не менял - и, по идее, он должен работать, а по факту - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл причину, но не понял смысла ошибки.

Как пытался подключиться Laravel:

```
'mysql' '--host=111.11.11.111' '--port=3306' '--user=root' '--password=password' '--default-character-set=utf8mb4' 'datatable'
```

Правильное подключение:

```
'mysql' '--host=localhost' '--port=3306' '--user=root' '--password=password' '--default-character-set=utf8mb4' 'datatable'
```

Вся проблема была в `host`, нужно указывать не IP адрес, а `localhost`.